# What is the difference b/n Session and Application objects?

Tags: asp.net

I know that Session is for a single user , and application is for multi user purpose.The Data in the application object is shared. Right? Then how can access the application data from an another client.

if My concept is wrong then what's right?

Comment: Your question isn't really clear.  What do you mean from another client?  Application data is accessible globally in your web app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application vs Session vs Cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096544/application-vs-session-vs-cache)

Answer (score 1):

A client cannot access directly from the `Application` object. The server will need to send data to the client (the way to do this will depend entirely on your scenario). The `Application` is the same as a static dictionary only that it is thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

for fist one answer application object means not only for single user .the enter in application is just like a data base it will store the data we are given and new user will access on not is only user option.